# How to solve the error "Error: Command failed to execute!" when installing Virtualbox on macOS using Homebrew?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, installation, virtual-machine, homebrew

I typed:

`brew cask install virtualbox`

and as result I got:

> ==> Satisfying dependencies
>   ==> Downloading http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.0/VirtualBox-5.2.0-118431-OSX.dmg
>   Already downloaded:
>   /Users/gsi-frank/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/virtualbox--5.2.0-118431.dmg
>   ==> Verifying checksum for Cask virtualbox
>   ==> Installing Cask virtualbox
>   ==> Running installer for virtualbox; your password may be necessary.
>   ==> Package installers may write to any location; options such as --appdir are ignored. Password:
>   ==> installer: Package name is Oracle VM VirtualBox
>   ==> installer: Installing at base path /
>   ==> installer: The install failed (The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software
>   manufacturer for assistance.) Error: Command failed to execute!
>
> ==> Failed command: /usr/bin/sudo -E -- /usr/sbin/installer -pkg /usr/local/Caskroom/virtualbox/5.2.0-118431/VirtualBox.pkg -target /
>
> ==> Standard Output of failed command: installer: Package name is Oracle VM VirtualBox installer: Installing at base path / installer:
>   The install failed (The Installer encountered an error that caused the
>   installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for
>   assistance.)
>
> ==> Standard Error of failed command:
>
> ==> Exit status of failed command:

I noticed the Virtualbox is installed and I even created a VM without problem, but my fear is that this error come to hunt me in the most inopportune moment ;)

How can I get rid of this error? What are the implications of this error? Where could I find more info about it? some log or something like that

macOS 10.13.1
brew updated

Answer (score 0):

High Sierra now requires explicit user permission before kernel extensions can be ran (KEXT)

read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2459/_index.html) (tl;dr Go to system preferences/security & privacy and click on allow VirtualBox)

enable virtualbox KEXT and then run

```
brew cask reinstall --force virtualbox
```